# Play a function for everyone using the website

Tags: java, function, message

How do I make a freature where anyone who has acces to a part of the website can play a function that involves everyone on the website? Basically a button that sends out " alert("Hello everyone!"); " to everyone that is using the website when that message gets sent out?

Basically mass message

Comment: This will be fairly complicated and will probably require backend programming as well as frontend. If you're using `alert`, I'd say you should probably take a step back and try something easier.

Comment: Well, since im way to unexperienced with coding, Would it work with wordpress?

Comment: Can't say, I don't know what backend capabilities WordPress offers. This will likely require sockets at the very minimum, so look into what is required to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need sockets to do this. Some browsers have already implemented sockets in Javascript/HTML5, but they're not standard for all browsers.
A little solution (even if it may not be really perfect) is that you call a page of your server with Ajax every x seconds.
The page will return like a message when there's a message to show, then Javascript when it loaded the page with Ajax will send an alert with the message.
I don't know if you get me. If you want further explanations about this concept just comment.

Comment: Tbh, I dont understand majority of that, mostly because im quite new to coding overall

Comment: Yay, I was right lol. And I should note, I made an instant chat page, and tried the "Ajax request every x seconds" approach. It ended up using *lot* more data than I anticipated, so I opted to use a refresh button instead of live updates. Also note, to do this, you'll need to know a backend framework/language such as PHP or Node.js.